# need to add the Json serialization settings in asp.net core web api controller method

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I add the following json serializaton setting :  TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All to the response so that the $type property is added to the response Json..How can i achieve this

```
[HttpGet("GetCustomerById")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(CustomerBase), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
      public virtual async Task<ActionResult<CustomerBase>> GetCustomerByIdAsync(int customerId)
        {
            try
            {
                if (customerId<= 0)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Invalid customerId in the request.");
                }

                _logger.LogDebug($"Getting Customer by Id : {CustomerId}");

                using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var customer= await scope.ServiceProvider
                        .GetRequiredService<ICustomerServerApiClient>()
                        .GetCustomerByIdAsync(CustomerId);

                    return Ok(customer);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogCritical($"Exception in Get Customer by Id: {CustomerId} " +
                                    $"Returning a 500 to the caller. Exception message: {ex.Message}. " +
                                    $"Stack trace: {ex.StackTrace}.");
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I could achieve my requirement

```
//return Ok(customer); replaced by below line
 return new JsonResult(customer) { SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All } };
```